# SQL Error [23514]: ERROR: new row for relation

Tags: sql, postgresql

While copying the data from a CSV file it's throwing the issue as:

> SQL Error [23514]: ERROR: new row for relation

The location of the CSV file and the table name have been checked.

I have tried using different delimiter which also ends up with the same error.

```
copy groups from 'C:/test.csv' DELIMITER '~';
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete SQL command you ran. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Is that really the full error message? Typically there is more, e.g. "*new row for relation foobar violates not-null constraint*" or "*new row for relation foobar violates check constraint ...*"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: And add typical some lines of the CSV....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grepping the PostgreSQL source, I assume that the error message really was:

```
new row for relation "%s" violates check constraint "%s"
```

You look at the definition of the constraint and the new row, then it will become clear why the error was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [list of Postgres error-codes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html) the error code `23514` means "check violation". So you should visit all the `CHECK` constraints defined on your table and find out, what the problematic constraint checks.

Note that the name of the constraint as well as the offending row are usually mentioned in the error message. It looks like you only posted part of it.